# Any way to download the strategy test results in Excel?

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

Is there any method to download the strategy performance details along with list of trades to excel in trading view. It also does not allow to copy paste from screen which would have been a crude method of getting list of trades.

Answer (score 0):

This extension copies the overview, settings, and the full list of trades directly to your clipboard.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autoview/okdhadoplaoehmeldlpakhpekjcpljmb